# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…) When looping through native objects

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to print out the a native object's API key/type to the console but I get Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…) error.

I think the issue is because some of the properties are created using getters and setters and when running typeof obj[keys[i]] it calls the function out of context.

```
function keys_vals( obj ) {
    var keys = Object.keys( obj );
    for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
        console.log( keys[i], typeof obj[keys[i]] );
    }
}
```

sample run

```
key_vals(Node.prototype)
---------------------------
ELEMENT_NODE 1 number
ATTRIBUTE_NODE 2 number
TEXT_NODE 3 number
CDATA_SECTION_NODE 4 number
ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE 5 number
ENTITY_NODE 6 number
PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE 7 number
COMMENT_NODE 8 number
DOCUMENT_NODE 9 number
DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE 10 number
DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE 11 number
NOTATION_NODE 12 number
DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED 1 number
DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING 2 number
DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING 4 number
DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS 8 number
DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY 16 number
DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC 32 number
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)
```

Comment: Just enhancing the method like `function key_vals(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    try {
      console.log(keys[i], typeof obj[keys[i]]);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(keys[i], e)
    }
  }
}` will give you the keys causing the error

Comment: It could be that, the property has a getter method which when invoked on a non NodeType instance throws the error, in your case you are invoking it on a prototype object

Comment: bruh im doing something with lots of iteration and that thing is happening too

Answer (score 0):

As Arun P Johny suggested this will print out the API, the issue is indeed because **when setting properties with getters and setters functions typeof obj[keys[i]] calls those function out of context.**

```
function keys_vals( obj ) {
    var keys = Object.keys( obj );
    for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
        try {
            console.log( keys[i], obj[keys[i]], typeof obj[keys[i]] );
        } catch ( e ) {
            console.log( keys[i], Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( obj, keys[i] ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `typeof obj[keys[i]]` doesn't call any function?

Comment: @Bergi I think if the property set using a setter /getter function those will be invoked and what is returned is what typeof will use

Comment: Yes, but why would a getter throw an `Illegal invocation` error? It's invoked on the `obj` it's installed on, there's not much to get wrong. In any case `typeof` got nothing to do with it.